# how to get custom filter values in controller in angular js

Tags: angularjs

```
 mainApp.filter('sumOfValue', function() {
    return function(data, key) {
      debugger;
      if (angular.isUndefined(data) || angular.isUndefined(key))
        return 0;
      var sum = 0;

      angular.forEach(data, function(v, k) {
        sum = sum + parseFloat(v[key]);
      });
      return sum;
    }
});
```

this is my filter.js. And the how to get values stored in controller in sumofvalue. Any one help me.`enter code here`

Comment: hi satheesh did u get the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use this filter as predefined filter in angular js
Here is the demo link [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dqayrqe1/1/)

**Js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
    id: 1,
    value: 'abc'
  }, {
    id: 1,
    value: 'test'
  }];
});

app.filter('sumOfValue', function() {
  return function(data, key) {
    if (key)
      return data.filter(function(obj) {
        return obj.value == key;
      });
    return data;
  }
});

app.run(function() {

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
  <div ng-controller='ctrl'>
    <input type='text' ng-model='search' placeholder='search'>
    <br>
    <span ng-repeat='item in data| sumOfValue: search'>
      {{item.value}}
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

this may help you.